# Getting error of "Can't find variable: _fbBatchedBridge" when launch react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native

I created a new react-native project and launch it on iphone simulator successfully. Now I want to launch it on a android simulator which is genymotion on a mac machine. I always got below error on android. I did some search and I can verify that my npm server started and listened on 8081 port. I also set my server ip and port on the simulator by clicking "Dev Settings" -> "Debug server host & port for device". But it is still not working. Is there any other place I need to check? I guess the simulator can't connect to my host machine but I don't know how to configure it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I solved this problem by updating genymotion to the latest version then added a android simulator with android 5.0. Previous I was using android 4.3 which is not working.